# Grunt is stuck when building tasks tree for ng-grid project in Webstorm in Windows 2012

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, webstorm, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I cannot setup ng-grid project in WebStorm under Windows 2012.
NPM and Grunt references are set correct.
Grunt references:

```
Node interpreter: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\node.cmd
Grunt-cli package: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\node\node_modules\grunt-cli\
```

NPM succeeded to install Grunt package:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\node\grunt -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\node\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt
grunt-cli@0.1.13 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\node\node_modules\grunt-cli
├── resolve@0.3.1
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.7)
└── findup-sync@0.1.3 (lodash@2.4.2, glob@3.2.11)
```

When I'm trying to reload tasks in WebStorm it is just stuck.
When I run grunt from terminal I get this:

```
grunt --force --verbose Gruntfile.js grunt
Initializing
Command-line options: --force, --verbose
Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK
Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading lib/test/angular/files.json...OK
Parsing lib/test/angular/files.json...OK
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
```

and it is stuck too.

Comment: Have you tried installing it again? I've had issues where something got left out when doing an `npm install`, but running it again made it work.

Comment: runned "npm install" and after that "bower install" - and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing it again? I've had issues where something got left out when doing an npm install, but running it again made it work.